# redis scanIterator configuration

Tags: node.js, redis

I am using the latest redis npm package and I'm trying to iterate through all the keys using the scanIterator(). Is it possible to configure the iterator to MATCH an expression.
Im using this configuration but it is still returning all the keys that don't match the expression.

```
 redisClient.scanIterator({
  TYPE: "string",
  MATCH: "key.*.dev",
  COUNT: 1
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by removing the TYPE parameter, MATCH and COUNT were enough to yield the filtered response